# Is there any way to fix this cell spacing problem in swift ios?

Tags: swift, uitableview, cell

[Space is not there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/55zMf.png)

[here i have not done anything specific but space is like i wanted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4fIyD.png)

I have tried many things but nothing is working, please help

Comment: Have you tried tinkering with the cell height?

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add bottom to the cell view to make a space at the bottom of each cell.